# Cordova Camera plugin error when large image is re-size using targetWidth & targetHeight

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am having problem with the camera plugin in Android using PhoneGap. The app stop working when I upload large images(2MB above) but not when I upload small size images.

Here is the sample code:

```
function browse_image(){
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, targetWidth: 600, targetHeight: 600 });
}
```

The image I am trying to used is 2.27MB with 2448x3264 pixels.

I am aware that when I remove the "targetWidth: 600 and targetHeight: 600" the plugin work will.

I would like to know if there is away to make the plugin work without removing the targetWidth & targetHeight option in the plugin

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: file an issue on http://issues.cordova.io/ so developers can evaluate it

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jcesarmobile ! I already found the problem, the problem is in the emulator. Maybe the emulator is not capable of storing the temporary data during the process. The script is working fine in real android device now.